# Fast way to write json files to Disk

Tags: java, json, performance, io, twitter

I have a project that fetch tweets from the Twitter API and I need to write them **(JSON)** to disk as fast as possible.  All the tweets go to the same file but, every 10 minutes, a new file is created to store the next tweets. Which is, in Java, the best way to do this? A simple FileWriter? a buffered one? mapped to memory?

Comment: Bare in mind, if you store them just in memory for 10 minutes if your app crashes you lose those tweets if you haven't persisted them.

Comment: BufferedWriters on a file outputstream should work fine, but why are you using files?  Using a DB would offload all of the hard "making sure your data is saved" stuff.  Twitter API rate limits your tweet fetching to such a level that your disk I/O will most probably not be the bottleneck.

Comment: The time that the Java (or another PL) takes to write data into disk depends heavily on the OS and, well, the disk technology.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza - true, but you can still achieve a x100 factor from code. usually for worse :-)

Comment: @bdares I have a big a amount of distributed fetchers so I store the tweets on their disk and periodically I send all to a centralized DB. Is isn't this the best way to do it?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza the fetch are executed in Windows, Linux and probably MacOS so I can't choose an OS based solution. I need to focus on my code.

Comment: It doesn't matter that much how you write exactly, but you should buffer writes as much as possible. And possibly write in a background thread.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about this too much right now, just write a separate component interface that all your calls go through, that uses something simple like FileWriter. Then if you find that file IO is a bottleneck later on, you can plug in a different implementation. Premature optimization is the devil!